# Pandas: Transform and merge a date interval into a dummy variable in a panel

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes, the main one is a monthly (MS) panel like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Date':pd.to_datetime(['1990-1-1', '1990-2-1']*2, yearfirst=True)})

        Date Location
0 1990-01-01        A
1 1990-02-01        A
2 1990-01-01        B
3 1990-02-01        B
```

The second one is a list of events that includes locations, start date and end date (month first), like this:

```
events = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['A', 'B'], 
                   'Start Date':pd.to_datetime(['1/14/1990', '1/2/1990']), 
                   'End Date':pd.to_datetime(['1/15/1990', '2/13/1990'])})

  Location Start Date   End Date
0        A  1990-01-14  1990-01-15
1        B  1990-01-02  1990-02-13
```

---

**What I need is to turn the start-and-end-date/location combos in the second dataframe into dummy variables in the first.  In other words, I need a column that takes on the value of 1 if a particular location had an event on a given date, 0 otherwise.  Like this:**

```
        Date Location  Event
0 1990-01-01        A      1
1 1990-02-01        A      0
2 1990-01-01        B      1
3 1990-02-01        B      1
```

As you can see, the date 1990-1-1 did not fall in the range of an event in the second dataframe for location B, so it's a 0.  Sometimes events will span multiple months, other times not.  The day of the event within the month is not relevant, since the main data is all MS frequency.  It's a large panel, so the same location will have events on many different dates, and the same date will have events in different locations.

---

The solution I've worked out is messy and not very fast:

```
events2 = pd.melt(events, id_vars='Location', 
                          value_vars=['Start Date', 'End Date'],
                          value_name='Event')

import datetime
def date_fill(g):
    #to make sure the 1st of a month is always in the range
    y, m = g['Event'].min().year, g['Event'].min().month
    date_range = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(year=y, month=m, day=1),
                               g['Event'].max(),
                               freq='MS')
    return g.set_index('Event').reindex(date_range,
                                        fill_value=g['Location'].iloc[0])

events3 = events2.groupby('Location', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: date_fill(g))
```

Which gives me this:

```
             Location variable
0 1990-01-01        A        A
1 1990-01-01        B        B
  1990-02-01        B        B
```

Which I can then clean up a bit, create a column of all 1s, and left-merge into the first dataframe on location and date, filling NaNs with 0.  It works, but it's obviously messy and slow (a smaller consideration than messy because the data isn't overly large). I feel like there must be a better way, but I haven't turned it up yet.

*Edit: There are actually several problems with my "solution" also, as I explore this more, which was my fear with such a messy bit of work.  Specifically it chokes on some corner cases, like when the event starts and ends on the 1st of the month (can't reindex with duplicates).*

Comment: Can you explain the result again? How to you assign each event.

Comment: @Tai I added some more explanation to the result part.

Comment: I still do not get it. Please explain why each is 1 and 0. What is the dummy variable matching on? The date is weird. 1990-01-01 is not within both events.

Comment: @Tai Yes, that's why it's a 0 for one of the location/dates and a 1 for the other, in the desired output.

Comment: you  confuse me. What is your "it" and what is your "other"? Say it out..

Comment: Can you unify your date format? There are two kinds of formats, right? year at the start and year at the end.

Comment: @Tai Converting the dates was done in the first two lines of my solution, but I moved it up to the data creation if that helps.  It was just the formatting from the actual data.

Comment: Thank you it is much more clear now. I appreciate it. I will try to work on it.

Comment: Why "1990-01-01        B " is 1?

Comment: @Tai Because it falls within the range of an event in the "events" dataframe.  Notice the row at index 1 in "events".  That, and as I mentioned the day of an event is irrelevant in the end, all that matters is month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should produce the desired output. (not fast)

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.to_period('M')
events["Start Date"] = events["Start Date"].dt.to_period('M')
events["End Date"] = events["End Date"].dt.to_period('M')
e_g = events.groupby("Location")   

def f(x):
    g = e_g.get_group(x.Location)
    return ((x.Date >= g["Start Date"])&(x.Date <= g["End Date"])).any()

df["dummy"] = df.apply(f, axis=1).astype(int)
df

    Date    Location  dummy
0   1990-01     A       1
1   1990-02     A       0
2   1990-01     B       1
3   1990-02     B       1
```

Comment: That's a lot cleaner than what I had been using, but it's extraordinarily slow.  Takes around 20 minutes to run on my data, but that's not a huge concern to me.  I did need to capture KeyError exceptions on the `get_group` line, so that the function can return `NaN` if the location doesn't match.  Thanks for this approach.

Comment: @Jeff I notice it is pretty slow but the answer is right. I did not notice the `NaN` part and hope you already took care of it. Hope other people can find you a better answer!